# Microsoft DateTime Json Conversion Problems

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

I have a Server Client architekture and I am trying to transport a DateTime value to the Client. Here is what my results in the Client are:

```
DateTime on Server 01.10.1980 00:00 (local. utc is -2h)
Incoming Json String "\"\\/Date(339199200000+0200)\\/\""
Deserialized DateTime Object: 30.09.1980 22:00 UTC Local: 23:00
```

Most of the Dates work, but there are some values (like above) that dont work. But I have no idea why. I am using Newtonsoft Json on both parts.

Changing the "+0200" at the end has almost no effect, sometimes its 22:00 and sometimes 23:00. But always wrong.

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you're using the date time offset instead of just date time. Datetime objects won't have time zone references.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason W!!
This really seemd to be the problem. 
I changed the `DateParseHandling` to `DateTimeOffset` and it just worked!

Comment: For more, see [Choosing between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime).